# SSIS combine 2 sources, Merge and Join not applicable

Tags: ssis

Goodday,

I have an issue with SSIS. I am currently trying to go from XML to SQL server.
The XML file is structured as follows:

```
<root>
    <metadata>
        <GUID>jiof01f0h8</GUID>
    </metadata>
    <infoINeed>
        <value1>1</value1>
        <value2>2</value2>
    </InfoINeed>
</root>
```

The issue at hand: I am using the XML Source task to extract the info I need. At the same time, I am extracting the GUID and transforming it into a real GUID datatype in a Derived Column task.

Now I need to combine the two to insert both at the same time into a SQL server table with the following structure:

```
   Value1    Value2    GUID
1   1         2         hvweh892
2   3         4         vwwvb11a
3   5         6         wehjk67k
```

Neither Merge nor Union will do the trick. Is there a solution that I am missing.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unclear, please post the exact xml that would produce the desired result, meaning post the xml including all three rows.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a RowCount transformation after each source, and then do a MERGE JOIN on the RowCount columns.